# Why semi-colon in python after end of print and variable working?

Tags: python, python-2.7

*I am new to python and currently working in it. 
I have write one simple program, as i read somewhere that semicolon not allowed or required in python to end statement. but i have use that and till its working fine! anyone explain me*

why its possible?

**here is code.**

```
a = 10;
if a == 10:
    print "value of a is %s"%(a);
else:
    print "value of a is not %s"%(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

semicolon is allowed as statement separator

```
>>> a=1;b=2;c=3
>>> print(a,b,c)
1 2 3
```

It is not required if you write each statement in a new line

Answer (score 0):

### Python does not require semi-colons to terminate statements. Semi-colons can be used to delimit statements if you wish to put multiple statements on the same line.